# A script to count the total number of products

Tags: php, sql, opencart

Essentially, I am looking for a script to count the total number of products that I have in my store and then place this total inside a div.

Comment: Assuming you haven't put any effort, no one will help you out.

Comment: Do you know the table in which the products are stored ? Do you know sql query? Then it's very simple and you can do it yourself. Have a nice day :) !

Comment: That you everyone for your suggestions and I am sorry for the lack on information, I have been looking around but I have a very limited knowledge in this area.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like what you need is NOT javascript at all.
If you are talking about OpenCart (as your title suggests), you need access to the total number of the products in your database (not in the page itself or DOM elements).

The 'professional approach' will be to extend your model and controller files with the correct methods,
but in case you are trying to avoid it (can't really recommend it) this is what you need to do.

```
<div>
<?php
  $query = $this->db->query("SELECT status FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "product WHERE status='1' ");
  $products_count = $query->rows ? count($query->rows) : 0;
  echo "Total products in store: " . $products_count;
?>
</div>
```

Again, since I'm a big fan of MVC structure, I'd recommend extending the controller and model to handle all the data, especially if you're going to use this in multiple view files. This way, you'll send the data to the view and all you'll have to do in your code will be:

```
<div>
   echo "Total products in store: " . $products_count;
</div>
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: You don't need to select every bit of data just for the row count. You can use `status` instead of the `*` which will return a lot less data and take far less memory

Comment: Good point Jay thanks! If you don't need the actual data but just the count, then it's better indeed to do the counting on the mysql side. However, Jay - please correct me if I'm wrong but I'm not sure if you can use the status keyword to count only enabled rows (some products can be disabled and we probably don't want them to show). You can use SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ... WHERE status='1' and that would be faster and more efficient than my first answer.

Comment: Not entirely correct no - `SELECT COUNT(*)` is still less efficient than simply `SELECT COUNT(status)`. I'm not actually sure if it's more efficient to use `COUNT` over using PHP to count the row total though would think so yes. Also, the `SELECT status` I mentioned in my previous message still needs the `WHERE` clause so it will still only return rows that have `status=1`

Answer (score 1):

In controller

```
$this->load->model('catalog/product'); 
//loads product model

$this->data['total_product'] = $this->model_catalog_product->getTotalProducts(); 
// gives the number of product
```

In template file

```
echo $total_product
```

This can be the most simple way to display total product, if you want to do this by script function Then define a function in Controller and call it using json from tpl.